# Drawing balls one at a time without replacement.

Tags: probability

A box contains two red and four yellow balls. Balls are drawn out of the box at random one at a time without replacement until two consecutive balls have the same color.What is the probability that the experiment will be over by 5 balls? 6 balls?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the sample space for 5 balls? Start with the simplest case - what is the probability that the experiment ends with 2 selections?

Comment: It may be easier to figure the probability of **not** getting two consecutive  balls of the same color, which you can then subtract from $1$. So, what's the probability of drawing all six balls with colors alternating between red and yellow? What's the probability for five balls?

Answer (score 1):

The only sequence which consists of $5$ balls is R,Y,R,Y,Y.

The probability for that sequence is $\frac26\cdot\frac45\cdot\frac14\cdot\frac33\cdot\frac22=\frac{1}{15}$.

The only sequence which consists of $6$ balls is Y,R,Y,R,Y,Y.

The probability for that sequence is $\frac46\cdot\frac25\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac22\cdot\frac11=\frac{1}{15}$.